# Rails order based on association doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-order-by

I’m trying to sort movies by release_date but it doesn’t work properly

```
@movies = Movie.where(id: movie_ids).recent
```

If I use the opposite scope (:old) it’s working but not with (:recent)

```
# Movie.rb

# Associations  
has_many :movie_countries, dependent: :destroy
has_many :countries, through: :movie_countries

# Scopes
scope :recent,    -> { includes(:movie_countries).order('movie_countries.release_date DESC') }
scope :old,       -> { includes(:movie_countries).order('movie_countries.release_date ASC') }
```

Example:

```
MovieCountry id: 1, movie_id: 1, release_date: '2018-01-01'
MovieCountry id: 2, movie_id: 2, release_date: '2019-01-01'
MovieCountry id: 3, movie_id: 3, release_date: '2020-01-01'

movies = Movie.recent
movies => [movie id: 1, movie id: 3, movie id: 2]

movies = Movie.old
movies => [movie id: 1, movie id: 2, movie id: 3]
```

As you can see, the :old scope works properly but not :recent

Backtraces with real data:

- Recent:

  SELECT "movies"."id" AS t0_r0, "movies"."external_id" AS t0_r1, "movies"."original_title" AS t0_r2, "movies"."original_language" AS t0_r3, "movies"."imdb_id" AS t0_r4, "movies"."tmdb_id" AS t0_r5, "movies"."rentrak_film_id" AS t0_r6, "movies"."running_time" AS t0_r7, "movies"."status" AS t0_r8, "movies"."website" AS t0_r9, "movies"."backdrop_url" AS t0_r10, "movies"."created_at" AS t0_r11, "movies"."updated_at" AS t0_r12, "movie_countries"."id" AS t1_r0, "movie_countries"."country_id" AS t1_r1, "movie_countries"."movie_id" AS t1_r2, "movie_countries"."release_date" AS t1_r3, "movie_countries"."iso_code" AS t1_r4, "movie_countries"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "movie_countries"."updated_at" AS t1_r6 FROM "movies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "movie_countries" ON "movie_countries"."movie_id" = "movies"."id" WHERE "movies"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80, $81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90, $91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100, $101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110, $111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118, $119, $120, $121, $122, $123, $124, $125, $126, $127, $128, $129, $130, $131, $132, $133, $134, $135, $136, $137, $138, $139, $140, $141, $142, $143, $144, $145, $146, $147, $148, $149, $150, $151, $152, $153, $154, $155, $156, $157, $158, $159, $160, $161, $162, $163, $164, $165, $166, $167, $168, $169, $170, $171, $172, $173, $174, $175, $176, $177, $178, $179, $180, $181, $182, $183, $184, $185, $186, $187, $188, $189, $190, $191, $192, $193, $194, $195, $196, $197, $198, $199, $200, $201, $202, $203, $204, $205, $206, $207, $208, $209, $210, $211, $212, $213, $214, $215, $216, $217, $218, $219, $220, $221, $222, $223, $224, $225, $226, $227, $228, $229, $230, $231, $232, $233, $234, $235, $236, $237, $238, $239, $240, $241) ORDER BY movie_countries.release_date DESC
- Old :

  SELECT "movies"."id" AS t0_r0, "movies"."external_id" AS t0_r1, "movies"."original_title" AS t0_r2, "movies"."original_language" AS t0_r3, "movies"."imdb_id" AS t0_r4, "movies"."tmdb_id" AS t0_r5, "movies"."rentrak_film_id" AS t0_r6, "movies"."running_time" AS t0_r7, "movies"."status" AS t0_r8, "movies"."website" AS t0_r9, "movies"."backdrop_url" AS t0_r10, "movies"."created_at" AS t0_r11, "movies"."updated_at" AS t0_r12, "movie_countries"."id" AS t1_r0, "movie_countries"."country_id" AS t1_r1, "movie_countries"."movie_id" AS t1_r2, "movie_countries"."release_date" AS t1_r3, "movie_countries"."iso_code" AS t1_r4, "movie_countries"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "movie_countries"."updated_at" AS t1_r6 FROM "movies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "movie_countries" ON "movie_countries"."movie_id" = "movies"."id" WHERE "movies"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47, $48, $49, $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57, $58, $59, $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67, $68, $69, $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77, $78, $79, $80, $81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87, $88, $89, $90, $91, $92, $93, $94, $95, $96, $97, $98, $99, $100, $101, $102, $103, $104, $105, $106, $107, $108, $109, $110, $111, $112, $113, $114, $115, $116, $117, $118, $119, $120, $121, $122, $123, $124, $125, $126, $127, $128, $129, $130, $131, $132, $133, $134, $135, $136, $137, $138, $139, $140, $141, $142, $143, $144, $145, $146, $147, $148, $149, $150, $151, $152, $153, $154, $155, $156, $157, $158, $159, $160, $161, $162, $163, $164, $165, $166, $167, $168, $169, $170, $171, $172, $173, $174, $175, $176, $177, $178, $179, $180, $181, $182, $183, $184, $185, $186, $187, $188, $189, $190, $191, $192, $193, $194, $195, $196, $197, $198, $199, $200, $201, $202, $203, $204, $205, $206, $207, $208, $209, $210, $211, $212, $213, $214, $215, $216, $217, $218, $219, $220, $221, $222, $223, $224, $225, $226, $227, $228, $229, $230, $231, $232, $233, $234, $235, $236, $237, $238, $239, $240, $241) ORDER BY movie_countries.release_date ASC

Comment: I don't see how that ORDER BY would produce incorrect results, there could be confusing results if NULLs were involved but nothing like the example. Could you show us some real data? Even just the release dates?

Comment: Try to change `includes` for `joins`. When you still have wrong order, it indicates the issues is in your data. Because provided "Example" is not reproducible and does not correspond to "Backtraces with real data".

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk it returns the same thing with `joins`. If I show you the result of the query you will only see returned movies and not the movie_countries (who has the `release_date` column)

Comment: Anyway, your "Example" is wrong: it returns right result on empty DB with 3 Movie and 3 corresponding MovieCountry. So, the issue is your data and no one can help you without it. I can just guess, that you have more than 1 MovieCountry per Movie with different `release_date`s.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk you're right. The issue is that the movie had 2 movie_countries... 1 from France with an old `release_date`, and another one with a `release_date` for December. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative to fix this issue :

```
# Movie.rb
scope :old,       -> {includes(:movie_countries).order('movie_countries.release_date ASC') }
scope :recent,    -> { old.reverse }
```

### SOLUTION

Thanks to[@PavelMikhailyuk 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289886/rails-order-based-on-association-doesnt-work-properly?noredirect=1#comment93474366_53289886) I found the solution

```
# Movie.rb
scope :recent,    -> (iso_code = 'FR') { includes(:movie_countries).where(movie_countries: {iso_code: iso_code}).order('movie_countries.release_date DESC') }
```

The problem was that my movie had 2 `movie_countries`.

```
[#<MovieCountry id: 8, country_id: 2, movie_id: 5, release_date: "2018-12-10", iso_code: "GB", created_at: "2018-10-23 15:23:09", updated_at: "2018-10-23 15:23:09">, 
 #<MovieCountry id: 7, country_id: 1, movie_id: 5, release_date: "2018-10-24", iso_code: "FR", created_at: "2018-10-23 15:23:09", updated_at: "2018-10-23 15:23:09">]
```

I must search the `movie_countries` for a specific country AND THEN sort them.

Comment: Keep in mind that calling `.reverse` will change your ActiveRecord association into an Array. This may or may not be what you intend.

Comment: You are right...
And `reverse_order` doesn't work properly :/

Comment: How about `includes(:movie_countries).order('movie_countries.release_date DESC')`

Comment: @Dbz This is what my original `recent` scope does :)

Comment: @Guillaume not quite. My suggestion returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` and the `recent` scope returns an `Array`. This may end up being very important, and at the very least the expected behavior should be consistent if not well documented

Comment: @Dbz my original scope is this one `scope :recent,    -> { includes(:movie_countries).order('movie_countries.release_date DESC') }`